# Extract quarter numbers from a data range

Tags: sql, oracle12c

Is there a way to extract the quarter numbers from a date range in an Oracle db?

Example
I would want the output as 1,2,3,4 for the date range - 01-01-2017 and 12-31-2017

Thank you!

Comment: (month - 1)/3 + 1?

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. This worked!

Comment: @Cindy - what do you mean by "from a date **range**"? Better yet: What are the inputs? Two dates? In what data type: `date`? or as strings (`varchar2`)? And what is the desired result - a single column, four rows, with the values 1, 2, 3, 4? Should the values be numbers, or strings? And what is the desired result for the "range" from 01-01-2015 to 12-31-2017?

Comment: @jarlh - what is the value of that expression when month is, say, 5? I get the answer 7/3. Did you mean to wrap that within `trunc(...)`? If so, why not the simpler `ceil(month/3)`? (Of course, "month" would have to be extracted from the date - which is why Baski's answer is better, even if the result must be wrapped within `to_number()`, depending on the exact requirement.)

Comment: @mathguy, I was expecting integer arithmetics, but perhaps Oracle doesn't work that way? (I'm not an Oracle guy.)

Comment: @jarlh - Sadly, no. Oracle doesn't do integer arithmetic. Even in PL/SQL, where you can use the INTEGER data type to force integer arithmetic in limited cases, you only have the integer arithmetic behavior; it is still implemented through floating-point operations (!!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_char function to extract quarter as well

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Q') from dual;
```